# Create React App iOS Add to Homescreen shows white page

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I have a react app with create-react-app and I want to make it possible for the user to add it to the homescreen.

This is my manifest file:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "React App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

When I add the app to the homescreen on iOS and open it, it will show a blank page. If I open it in safari it works fine. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Also looking into the best way to avoid this problem. For now, I found this: https://ayastreb.me/react-router-in-home-screen-pwa/

Basically use hash routing.